# Decreasing spacing between two lines in HTML

Tags: html, css

HTML n00b here. I can't paste my actual code because it's from work, but basically I have

```
<p>Some text</p>
<p><a href="SomeSite.com">Some more text</a></p>
```

and I want those lines to be stacked on top of each other while the rest of the lines on the page maintain their normal spacing between each other.

I tried doing

```
<p style="padding-bottom: 0px">Some text</p>
<p><a style="padding-top: 0px" href="SomeSite.com">Some more text</a></p>
```

but that didn't work. It seems like it ***should*** work.

Please show me how to do it in proper HTML fashion and explain why my attempt failed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will want to do something like this:

```
<p>Some Text <br /> <a href="">Some more text</a></p>
```

The `<br />` is a line break, so you can have everything in 1 paragraph and the line break will bring the next line under the first.  Then, you can use `line-height:10px`

```
<p style="line-height:10px;">Some Text <br /> <a href="">Some more texth</a></p>
```

You can change your px size to whatever.

If you NEED to have two separate paragraphs, you can enclose them in a container and give the `line-height` to the container.

```
<div style="line-height:10px">
    <p>line 1</p>
    <p><a>line 2</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use a `span` tag instead of `p` tag as `p` tag will automatically will start in a new line

so you should either use `display:inline` in css or use a `span` tag

```
<span>Some text</span>
<span><a href="SomeSite.com">Some more text</a></span>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bp48N/)

I just misunderstood your question,so i have the answer below
HTML

```
<p>Some text</p><br/>
<p><a href="SomeSite.com">Some more text</a></p>
```

CSS:

```
p{
    display:inline;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bp48N/1/)

Comment: This does not accomplish what the poster is asking. This just puts the two lines on the same line. What the poster is looking to do is to have the two lines right on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you mean.

But it sounds like you want a line break, rather than a paragraph.

So...

```
<p>Sometext<br><a href="#">Some other text</a></p>
```

The `<br>` tag is for line breaks.

For more info be sure to checkout w3school: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_paragraphs.asp
It's a great resource for learning web design.

Answer (score 0):

You can use {line height: some %tage;} property....
like this
`line height : 30;`
for whatever div or tag you want to use it...
please upvote me this is my first ever answer on stackoverflow